# Как изменить класс элемента в Angular?

Tags: typescript, angular

У меня есть кнопка с текстом, который генирируется каждые 3 секунды.
Мне нужно сделать так, чтоб при появлении в тексте ноля, тексту добавлялся новый класс.
У меня уже есть проверка на содержание ноля в строке. Как добавить класс элементу, в котором этот текст?
Typescript code:

```js
export class TextFieldComponent implements OnInit {
  randomString:string = '';
  
  constructor() {
    this.getString();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const source = interval(3000);
    source.subscribe(() => this.getString())
  }

 getString(){
    this.randomString = '';
    while (this.randomString.length < 5) {
      this.randomString = btoa(Math.random().toString()).substr(10, 5);
    }
   this.whatStringCreated(this.randomString)
    return this.randomString;
  }

  whatStringCreated(randomString:string){
    if(this.randomString.includes('0')){
      this.containZero();
    }
}
containZero(): void{
   //???
    console.log("0");
  }
```

Html code:

```html
<div [className]="'d-grid gap-2 m-5'">
  <button type="button" id="textField" [className]="'btn btn-primary fs-1'" (click)="getString()" style="height: 100px; letter-spacing: 0.5em">{{randomString}}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: возможно стоит посмотреть на `ngClass`

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, использовать `[className]="'d-grid gap-2 m-5'"` в данном контексте не имеет смысла, так как имя класса не меняется и не генерируется, можно использовать обычный атрибут `class`.

Во-вторых, для того, чтобы проверить есть ли подстрока в строке, можно использовать метод `.includes()`.

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  randomString: string = '';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setInterval(() => this.getString(), 3000);
  }

  getString() {
    this.randomString = '';
    while (this.randomString.length < 5) {
      this.randomString = btoa(Math.random().toString()).substr(10, 5);
    }
    return this.randomString;
  }

  get containZero(): boolean {
    return this.randomString.includes('0');
  }
}
```

```css
.has-zero {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button [ngClass]="{'has-zero': containZero}" (click)="getString()">{{randomString}}</button>
```